# Beanvalidation with jax-ws and apache-cxf

Tags: eclipse

Apache-CXF 3.0.0 will contain BeanValidation. I really would like to use that, but we are using 2.7.7.

I'm new to WebService and I wonder what the current way is, to validate the incoming XML in a Webservice? For example, I would like to have something like @NotNull.